# How to merge two sets of enums in kotlin having the same parent interface?

Tags: android, enums, kotlin

I'm trying to do the following:

```
val list = MyEnum1.values().filterIsInstance(MyParentInterface::class.java)
       .plus(MyEnum2.values().filterIsInstance(MyParentInterface::class.java))
```

On Android Studio, lint is complaining that `filterIsInstance` is a "useless call on collection type". However, if I remove it, the `plus(MyEnum2.values()...` doesn't work because they are not of the same type.

Is that the right way to merge the values of two enums into a single list?

Edit: My enums look like this:

```
enum class MyEnum1 : MyParentInterface {
    ENUM1_TYPE1, ENUM1_TYPE2
}
```

Comment: I can get around the problem replacing `.filterIsInstance` with `.map { it as MyParentInterface }` but it still seems like not the best solution.

Comment: Can you post the definition of your Enums?

Comment: @Ascorbin sure. Nothing fancy about them though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a list explicitly as MyParentInterface and then just add values of your Enums.

```
val result = mutableListOf<MyParentInterface>()
return result.plus(MyEnum1.values())
        .plus(MyEnum2.values())
```

Comment: You're declaring mutable list and than not mutating it at all. `plus` operator creates a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert value arrays to lists and then concatenate them:

```
val sum: List<MyParentInterface> = MyEnum1.values().asList() + MyEnum2.values().asList()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns a `List<Any>` instead of  `List<MyParentInterface>`

Comment: That's true, seems that explicit type specification is required, because the compiler cannot decide if it shoud be `List<MyParentInterface>` or `List<Enum<*>>`. I've updated the answer.